# Button after click remains pressed till end of method

Tags: android, button, soundpool

I would like to use the same button to start and stop playing some sounds with a for loop inside function play().
I thought to use lock variable to do this, but button after click remains pressed till the function play end is execution.
Can you suggest some solution?

I have a situation like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
   private static SoundPool sound;
   static int lock=1;
   int s;

   @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    sound=new SoundPool(20, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 100);
    s=sound.load(this,R.raw.bipsound, 0);
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

}
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(lock) {
        case 0: 
            lock=1;
            break;

        case 1:
            lock=0;
            play();
            break;  
    }   
}

public void play(){
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        sound.play(s,1.0f, 1.0f, 1, 0, 1);
        if(lock==1)
            return;
        try {Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem `try {Thread.sleep(1000);` inside `play()`. You are telling the main `Thread` to `sleep` which is almost always a bad idea. The `Button` becomes pressed and remains in that state until the `sleep()` time has finished.

Remove that line. And I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish there but you can run it in a separate `Thread` with things like `TimerTask`, use a `handler` or other such features. If you need more help then please explain what you are trying to do with that.

Answer (score 0):

That's normal because you're using `try {Thread.sleep(1000);` and it stop the main thread during 1 seconde.

You've to use an AsyncTask to do that :)

Here's an example.

```
private void goToMainActivity() {
        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);
                Intent intent = new Intent(fa, Main.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }.execute();
    }
```